# Create 2 tkinter windows one of which 'blinks' open and closed

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create 2 tkinter windows, one that stays constant(win1) and one that closes and reopens at a set interval(win2). Ultimately I will pass a list of coordinates for win2 to iterate through so that it will open in a different position each pass of the loop.

Below is the code I am using to try and do this. Currently I get this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command:  application has been destroyed
invalid command name "4349633280<lambda>"
while executing
"4349633280<lambda>"
("after" script)
```

How can I do this? I am also open to using a different GUI if necessary.

```
import tkinter as tk

tk.NoDefaultRoot()

win1 = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(win1, text='Spam').pack()
v=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in v:
    win2 = tk.Tk()
    win2.after(300, lambda: win2.destroy())

win1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you create the six windows almost at the same time and then schedule six tasks to destroy them.  However you use same variable `win2` for the six windows, therefore `win2` finally references only to the last window.  When the first schedule task is executed, `win2` is destroyed.  When the second schedule task is executed, it tries to destroy `win2` but it is already destroyed which causes the exception.

Also you should use `Toplevel` for `win2`.  It is not recommended to have more than one instance of `Tk()`.

Below is an example to use `after()` to do what you want:

```py
import tkinter as tk

win1 = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(win1, text="Spam").pack()

def blink_window(win2=None, n=6):
    if win2:
        win2.destroy()
    if n > 0:
        win2 = tk.Toplevel()
        win2.after(300, blink_window, win2, n-1)

blink_window()
win1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

To do this you cannot use lambda without a default argument, but you don't need it at all. Also you should use Toplevel instead of Tk to make the additional windows.

```
import tkinter as tk

tk.NoDefaultRoot() # this seems useless ... 

win1 = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(win1, text='Spam').pack()
v=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in v:
    win2 = tk.Toplevel(win1)
    win2.after(300, win2.destroy) # close child window in 300 milliseconds

win1.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"you cannot use lambda"_ is a false statement. It's not needed, but it's still possible to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does not accomplish the blinking effect I am going for. When I run this all 6 child windows appear at once and all close after 300 milliseconds. I want win1 to be displayed the whole time the code is running while win2 opens, stays open for n milliseconds, closes, and then reopens in a loop 6 times. I don't think this can be done using child windows because mainloop() effectively freezes the code. This is why I was trying to use tk.NoDefaultRoot() so that the two windows are independent of one another. Thanks again and please let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: @EvanLawrence I was just showing you how to get past this one problem of yours, I was not trying to solve your entire assignment. You take it from here. Yes, it should be done use Toplevel child windows, and no, tk.NoDefaultRoot() does not make the windows "independent".